# iptables how to block bittorrent?

Tags: iptables, bittorrent

I need to block all bittorrent traffic using iptables. As I know, bittorrent can adapt to existing firewall filters and send packages considering rules. But I can't  figure out how to counter this. So I tried some iptables rules I found on the internet but nothing really helps. Sometimes bittorrent protocol packages stop being received but traffic is still coming regardless of bittorrent protocol packages. I should mention that I can't just block everything except a couple ports I need. I have to block only bittorrent traffic.

So I tried this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "BitTorrent" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "BitTorrent protocol" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "peer_id=" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string ".torrent" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "announce.php?passkey=" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "torrent" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "announce" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "info_hash" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
```

Also I duplicated this rules but changed INPUT to OUTPUT and FORWARD. So at the moment I had 8 * 3 = 24 rules at the same time. After that I added the same rules, but using ip6tables instead iptables to block all ipv6 traffic.

After that I tried to add some additional rules:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m ipp2p --bit -j DROP
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m ipp2p --bit -j DROP
```

I also duplicated these rules using ip6tables, OUTPUT and FORWARD.

To summarize, I have added rules for blocking bittorrent traffic based on two methods:

1. According to concrete patterns in package
2. Using ipp2p module

But nothing really helps. I tried the first and second approach simultaneously and separately. The best result I could get (while using all rules at the same time) was 1 minute delay of torrent file downloading start, but after a minute the connection establishes.

Also when I tried the first approach (with patterns) I found interesting [package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFdJP.jpg). For some reason it has the pattern that I just filtered out. Maybe the way I filter by pattern is wrong? (--algo kmp/bm flag does not seem to change anything)

Maybe someone has already solved this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 22 inside VirtualBox. I use qBittorrent, Wireshark.

Should I provide any additional information?

P.S. I'm starting to concern that it's just impossible, but anyway, i want to try

Comment: actually bittorrent clients usually randomize the port used and the protocol could be encrypted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_protocol_encryption.  Moreover it use dht so any iplist is quite useless. the rules you are using were correct a decade ago

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Linux IPTables, How to block torrents or any P2P protocols?](https://serverfault.com/questions/27088/using-linux-iptables-how-to-block-torrents-or-any-p2p-protocols)

Comment: Rather than only disallowing a specific protocol generally the enterprise approach is to do the opposite:  disallow everything and prohibit all direct internet access.  Mandate the authenticated use of an HTTP proxy (that does TLS decryption and layer 7 inspection) for normal users and business applications that need internet access. Only for valid business applications that can't use a proxy specific exceptions will be granted, as restrictive as possible.